# SUM of SUM in BigQuery without duplicates

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with a one-to-many relationship of a business' name to a ZIP code, due to multiple industry codes matching that business for a given ZIP code. A separate table contains households by ZIP codes. To sum the households by business name for a range of ZIP codes without duplicates, I query:

```
SELECT DBAName, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode) AS SumHouseholds  
FROM Business  
JOIN Location  
ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
WHERE ZIPCode like '1001%' and DBAName = 'ABC Plumbing'  
GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode, Households  
ORDER BY SumHouseholds Desc
```

And get:

```
Row DBAName SumHouseholds  
1   ABC Plumbing    30  
2   ABC Plumbing    25  
3   ABC Plumbing    5
```

Each row represents a distinct ZIP code within the range, and its deduplicated sum of households. However, I'd like to sum the SumHouseholds from those rows = 60. When I try to nest SELECT statements for this:

```
SELECT DBAName, SUM(SumHouseholds) AS TotalHouseholds FROM (  
SELECT DBAName, SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode) AS SumHouseholds  
FROM Business  
JOIN Location  
ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode  
WHERE ZIPCode like '1001%' and DBAName = 'ABC Plumbing')  
GROUP BY DBAName  
ORDER BY TotalHouseholds
```

It returns the the sum of Households for all matching records *with* duplicates. Since 3 records match the query for each ZIP code, the result is `30x3+25x3+5x3=180`.

How should I change the query to return `SUM(SumHouseholds)=60`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below

```
SELECT DBAName, SUM(SumHouseholds) AS TotalHouseholds 
FROM (
  SELECT DBAName, ZIPCode, SUM(Households) AS SumHouseholds
  FROM Business
  JOIN Location
  ON Location.ZIPCode = Business.ZIPCode
  //WHERE ZIPCode LIKE '1001%' AND DBAName = 'ABC Plumbing'
  GROUP BY DBAName, ZIPCode
)
GROUP BY DBAName
ORDER BY TotalHouseholds
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the total deduplicated by following your syntax, using SUM(Households) OVER (PARTITION BY ZIPCode) AS SumHouseholds, and adding Households to the inner GROUP BY.

Comment: Would you have a recommendation for subselects on the example above, if instead of a single TotalHouseholds, the output desired would be separate columns of SUM(SumHouseholds) specific to multiple discrete DBAName values declared in the WHERE(s)?

Comment: it is not totally clear what exactly you mean and comments dont allow to go into much details. I would recommend you to post new question with all details and examples so i (or someone else) will be able to answe rit